# Export attachments from a feature class with сyrillic symbols

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, feature-class, python-script-tool, attachments

I found a .py script which export attachments from a feature class [(here)](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011912)

But it doesn't work with Cyrillic symbols in name of attachments.
How to specify the value of the encoding in the script and correct the error?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
import os

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID']) as cursor:
for item in cursor:
    attachment = item[0]
    filenum = "ATT" + str(item[2]) + "_"
    filename = filenum + str(item[1])
    open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
    del item
    del filenum
    del filename
    del attachment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID']) as cursor: 
    for item in cursor:
        attachment = item[0] filenum = u"ATT" + unicode(item[2]) + u"_"
        filename = filenum + unicode(item[1])
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
```